# Second minimum date in power bi

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerquery, datediff

I have some users with different game_id.

[image: fig1-my data]

for each user, I want to find the second minimum date. (column: min2_date)
If a user doesn't have a second date (look at user_id: 2, in this example), his min2_date should be -1.
If the second minimum date is the same as the first minimum date(look at user_id: 4), we should write that date in the min2_date column.

[image: fig2-True result]

I don't know **How I should calculate the second minimum date in Power BI.**
please help me if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you dont want a real second min date (but date in second row by order), we must try some trickyway.
One of way that we can do that is:

```
MinDate2 = 
var _countrows = CALCULATE(countrows(VALUES(games[dates])), ALL(games[dates]) )
return
if(_countrows = 1, -1, 
FORMAT(DISTINCT(TOPN(1,TOPN(2,CALCULATETABLE(SELECTCOLUMNS(games, "dates",games[dates]), ALL(games[dates])),[dates], asc), [dates], desc)), "yyyy-mm-dd")
)
```

where MinDate and MinDate2 are measures.

[image]

AS a calculatedColumn:

```
MinDate2_col = 
var _countrows = CALCULATE(countrows(VALUES(games[dates])), ALL(games[dates]) )
return
if(_countrows = 1, "-1", 
FORMAT(DISTINCT(TOPN(1,TOPN(2,CALCULATETABLE(SELECTCOLUMNS(games, "dates",games[dates]), ALL(games[dates])),[dates], asc), [dates], desc)), "yyyy-mm-dd")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @msta42a but it's a measure. I don't want a measure, I want to have MinDate2 as a column. for each game_id, I need it.

Comment: check update; if you want this as a Column then change argument in if (all must by a string because of different type and vairant is not allowed in calculatedcolumn), if you want date type, then replace "-1" with BLANK()

Comment: I changed my question in a new post.  I should delete this question from here. you can see my edited question using this link: https://b2n.ir/j35309  if you know the answer, please help me.